# How to create a custom payment page attached to a user account's form

Tags: 7, payment-gateways

I am on Drupal 7 and I am building an ads website in which people can buy credits via their account form. **I am not using Commerce or Ubercart** for very complex reasons that would be a bit long to explain.

So lets move forward.

Users will use the credit that they buy to make payable actions on their content, **such as making a content sticky**.

**1. What I already did :**

Now a user who is connected to his account can select the **number of credits** to add to his **balance**. And the balance will be added that amount of credits.

And all the payable action on the ads decrease the balance of the concerned user.

So to say that the system works fine.

**2. What I need to do now :**

I set up field to let the user choose the type of payment his wants : **PayPal** or **Credit Card**.

- How can I create a payment page without programming ?
- How can I make people really see a payment page ?
- How can I make that payment page appear before the users saves the
  account forms ?

These are the things that I really need to know.

**Anybody know how to ?**

Answer (score 1):

I think that this site will tell you what to do:

[Setting up payment methods](https://www.drupal.org/node/2383859)

You shall download one of the modules to get a list of services.

Comment: I am studying carefully from your answer @Jonathan Dalgaard.

Comment: Thanks I really hope that you will find a quick solution.

Comment: I think that you shall download the payment module.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I advice you the two modules its very helpful and I used the before to achieve similar scenario as you asked.

1- [commerce node checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout):

allow you to charge users to create nodes. It is possible to have multiple different product offerings for each node type, so the user can pick the product they want to purchase when creating the node. An example use-case would be a classifieds site that charges people to post listings

2- [commerce account balance](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_account_balance):

enables a -per user- account balance to which you can deposit money and which you can use for purchasing things on your website.

You could use any payment method like paypal to charge balance.

I think both two modules will do most of the job for you, if you don't need to use **commerce** which is required by the two modules try to patch them and customize or even get the main ideas and build your own solution.

**Edit:** [payment forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/payment_forms) may help if none of the above fits your needs.

Comment: I am studying carefully from your answer @Mohammed Gomma.

Comment: If the answer helps you, then up vote and accept.